# Google OAuth redirect urls with a custom domain name extension

Tags: google-oauth

I would like to set the redirect URL for a Google App Im creating as `app.dev.ddc/oauth2Callback` or `app.qa.ddc/oauth2Callback`.

However, it appears the redirect URL can only be `localhost` or a url ending with `.com`. 
Is this a known limitation.?

If so, is there any workaround my specific scenario..?

Answer (score 1):

As [The OAuth 2.0 Authorization Framework](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-3.1.2) says:
The redirection endpoint URI MUST be an absolute URI as defined by [RFC3986 Section 4.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-4.3).

Why you need this special redirect_uri?

Comment: My URIs look like http://apps.xyz.ddc which i think is a valid URI. Its just that Google Configuration does not allow any other extension than .com , so only http://apps.xyz.com works, but my app does not have a .com extension

Comment: Google does not support custom scheme. But for native client, here is a reference: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/oauth2-dev/P7bY0dThhuQ/-Z1p_2yJi9sJ